# Error .htaccess al subir al hosting

Tags: php, .htaccess, hosting

Actualmente tengo este código que en local me funciona sin problemas el problema viene al subirlo al hosting que me da error 500.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Por favor, trata de revisar los logs y traer un mensaje de error más detallado :) Luego lo pones yendo a [edit]

Answer (score 0):

1. Comprueba si **AllowOverride** está activo en tu hosting (httpd.conf).
2. El siguiente paso es comprobar que el módulo **ModRewrite** está activo.
3. Necesitas la instrucción **RewriteEngine on** que debería estar activa ya que si te funciona en localhost